# How to install py.test?

Tags: python, installation, add-on, pytest, instructions

So I am new to Python. This may be a very foolish question, but I have no idea how to install packages as `pytest`?

It would be great if somebody could give instructions in order to achieve this.

Comment: Please specify the OS

Comment: I am running windows 8 with python 3.3.

Answer (score 10):

In general, installing a package in Python is pretty simple if you use `pip` which is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4.

In order to install `pytest`:

**Python 2**: `$ pip install pytest`

**Python 3**: `$ pip3 install pytest`

However, it is a good practice to isolate Python environments by creating a virtual environment. In order to install `pytest` in an isolated virtual environment:

**Python 2**

```
$ pip install -U virtualenv
$ python -m virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate # in Windows -> $ venv\Scripts\activate.bat
$ pip install pytest
```

**Python 3**

```
$ pip3 install -U virtualenv
$ python3 -m virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate # in Windows -> $ venv\Scripts\activate.bat
$ pip install pytest
```

**Python 3.6+**

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate # in Windows -> $ venv\Scripts\activate.bat
$ pip install pytest
```

Comment: Is it a trick to use _specific pytest_ default version? I'm under _Debian-Jessie-like distro_, so python 2.7 is default. If I creates a venv with `python3.6 -m venv .venv`, and install _pytest_ after activate this venv with `pip install pytest==3.7.1`, the version called by `pytest --version` is `This is pytest version 3.2.1 imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest.pyc setuptools registered plugins` , if I want to use the newly installed version I have to call `python -m pytest --version`. If this need a dedicated question, I'll do.

Comment: @freezed, if your default version is Python 2, then you have first to install Python 3. Or you should use `pip install -U virtualenv` to install a virtual environment using python 2. What is the output you are getting after activating your virtual environment if you run `which python`, and what is the output you get when you run `which pip` (again after activating the virtual environment).

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/freezed/58bd7e81d514e41dd8acf32bde7697ee) is paths of python in/outside venv. [Here](https://framapic.org/CiQs3jcdVNus/4kmCV4zSOmS7.png) is a screenshot of my troubles… but today, I cannot reproduce this behavior… pytest in venv corresponds to the venv python branch… I put this on side, I will see if it happens again. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like pip.

For example, if you want to install Cherrypy you must to run

```
    pip install cherrypy
```

or if you're using python3, and depending of your distro, the command is

```
    pip3 install cherrypy
```

If you're downloading a package from source, then you must to uncompress it and normally, depending the package, you must to run (as administrator or root)

```
    python setup.py install
```

Comment: Suggesting to use pip with sudo is not a great idea and should only be done with care.

Comment: What exactly is "with care"?